# Firebase Console Authentication Add New User Button Not Displayed

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

I am using Firebase Authentication.  In the console, under my project, I choose Authentication -> Users and the Users Table is shown.  However, the Add New User button is not available.  Its simply not there.  I cannot add a new user manually.

Any idea why that might be?

Email/Password and Google Login are enabled.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

under "sign-in methods" (the next tab)... you'll have to enable the "Email / Password" sign-in provider, otherwise one obviously cannot add users manually.
[image]

Comment: Thank you.  But Email/Password is enabled, as is Google Login.

Comment: when I enable the "email / password" provider, the "add user" button turns blue (clickable) instantly... rather wonder where you might be looking for for the button; just added a screenshot. Google Login is useless in this case, because one cannot manually add to this Auth provider.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts.  Its not that the button is disabled.  It is just not there.

Comment: I don't know how to paste an image here.  My screen looks exactly like yours, but without the blue Add User button.  It is not there.  Not on any of my projects.

Comment: @user2690440 maybe try another browser once (just to rule out plugin and/or CSS issues)... here the button is either grayed out or bluish, depending if one has email login enabled whether or not. you could use a DOM inspector (press `F12`) and move the mouse where the button should be; would assume that at least it's markup should be present, despite invisible.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  I tried it in MS Edge, and there is the button!  And I do not see it in Inspector.  Must be a plugin.  Thank you!

Comment: For the benefit of anyone else who encounters this issue.  The culprit was ng-inspector for AngularJS 0.5.10  I turned it off and Add New User is back.  I have been using Chrome.

Comment: @user2690440 the ng-inspector seems to break more than just one page:
https://github.com/rev087/ng-inspector/issues ...maybe file the issue there, as another example of what it breaks.

Comment: Angular related chrome extension cause this issue..and its restricting to rendering "AddUser" button.I uninstall ng-inspector extension..its working as expected..